# How to send SMS with emoji in string using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-core, sms, emoji

I want to send SMS with text featuring emoji's in it: ️✨

```
var message = "Thank you for using Our Product ️ ✨ Be Happy Be Safe!";
```

I have tried like this, but that's not working:

```
var message = "Thank you for using Our Product" + HttpUtility.HtmlEncode("U+1F3CD") + " " + HttpUtility.HtmlDecode("U+2728") + " Be Happy Be Safe!";
```

I am using above string as SMS content tried `HttpUtilityEncode` and emoji unicode but still not able to send SMS getting exception that can't send sms with these characters.

```
private void SendSMS(string number, string message)
{
    var response = Post(number, message);
    Validate(response);
}
```

Comment: Does the SMS service provider you are using support Unicode and emojis?

Comment: @DenisMicheal i am using .net core WebClient DowloadString

Comment: The api you are calling with the WebClient. Does it support these characters?

Comment: yes it supports

Comment: Maybe you need to as an SMS provider support what the text format for emoji should look like.

Comment: Are you using Twilio?

Answer (score 0):

Try using Twilio. Refer the below steps for reference:

1. Create twillio account and get the account secret ID and AuthToken
2. Install `Install-Package Twilio` using nuget package manager
3. Pass in you account secret Id and Auth token to the below program

Refer the below code :

```
using System;
using Twilio;
using Twilio.Rest.Api.V2010.Account;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        // Twilio Account SID and Auth Token
        const string accountSid = "your_account_sid";
        const string authToken = "your_auth_token";

        
        TwilioClient.Init(accountSid, authToken);

        // Twilio phone number (must be purchased on Twilio)
        const string fromNumber = "your_twilio_phone_number";

        // Recipient's phone number
        const string toNumber = "recipient_phone_number";

        // Message content with emoji
        const string messageBody = "Thank you for using Our Product ️ ✨ Be Happy Be Safe!";

        // Send SMS
        var message = MessageResource.Create(
            body: messageBody,
            from: new Twilio.Types.PhoneNumber(fromNumber),
            to: new Twilio.Types.PhoneNumber(toNumber)
        );

        Console.WriteLine($"SMS sent with SID: {message.Sid}");
    }
}
```